# Skype (not installed) launch attempted at user login on Windows 10 computer

Tags: windows-10, skype

Windows 10
Skype NOT installed.
A short list of actually installed software.
Main use: LibreOffice Write, Calc and Thunderbird.
Some use of Firefox to browse the web.

Just recently this dialog has started to pop up at ONE user's login:
[image: Windows dialog; error finding Skype.exe]

Swedish text: Cant find the file C:\Program files...  \Skype\Skype.exe
Verify that you have given the correct name and try again.

Windows key+R and "msconfig" =>
Shows no software that seem to be logically related.

Windows key+R and "regedit", Search for "skype.exe" =>
Several hits that refer "repository" in the 'path', one matching the path in the dialog.

And as stated above: Control panel, Programs & Features: A very short list.

**Edit/repeat:** Skype is and has **not** ever been installed (as far as I know), so the fact that skype.exe is missing is "ok" and **expected**. The fact that "some THING tries to start it" is the actual problem.

I'd appreciate any tips on how to locate the cause for this.

Comment: You should download and install the current Windows Store version of Skype to solve this problem.  Windows Store applications are not lost in the control panel typically, they are listed, within Settings

Comment: Hmm... I think I'll try that before anything else. I can imagine installing remedies the problem, I hope it can be removed just after that; as it will not get used - no need to have it remain installed. I believe there *is* a windows account now that you mention it. Had forgot about that. I usually avoid that type of accounts as the plague - IMO they're not entirely meant for the benfit of the user (I'm the one who installed/initialized Windows).

Comment: I am a Windows user primarily but I have to say.. judging by the apps you run.. if ever someone should probably run Linux instead, it would be you.

Comment: There is no choice with this machine. Personally i DO run Linux since few years back.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your Image File Execution Options is blocking execution of Skype.exe. Go the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options`, find a key named `skype.exe` then delete the `Debugger` value.

Then you can look at the Startup keys `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` and delete Skype related entries.

Comment: Note: searching for skype.exe did not show anything in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` - I would have deleted that if there had been such an entry.

Comment: No... Look in the other key as well as too

Comment: Right, will do as I have access to that machine. Thanks for the info.

Comment: The executable is missing.  This answer doesn’t make sense, the error is clear, something has caused the Skype executable to be deleted but kept the key that automatically starts Skype when a user logs in

Comment: As far as I know skype has never been installed. (not my machine, I visit and attempt to help with problems)

Comment: This one is Skype UWP, and if Debugger is blocked then app won't run

Comment: Again: Skype is **not** installed, so the fact that skype.exe is missing is "ok" and **expected**. The fact that "some THING tries to start it" is the actual problem.